# Хорошие практики при загрузке изображений на сайт

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, хостинг-изображений

В сети существует много рекомендаций, как проектировать загрузку пользователями изображений на веб-сайт (в том числе и особеннно - т.н. 'highload') - но эти статьи описывают в основном сайты на unix-технологиях ([раз](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/04/22/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9/), [два](https://habrahabr.ru/company/io/blog/258363/)), т.н. LAMP или сейчас уже чаще LEMP.

Собственно, типовые операции там какие? Чаще всего это что-то из набора:

1. Проверка расширения и MIME-типа загружаемых файлов
2. Пересохранение картинок с 99% качеством (для пользователя разницы не видно, а решается задача удалить вредоносный код, если он там есть)
3. Уменьшение размера хранения файла -- как за счёт пересжатия картинки, так и за счёт удаления метаинформации
4. Подготовка миниатюр картинок (на лету либо заранее)
5. Сохранение картинки в облако
6. Отдача картинок с быстрых серверов статики (nginx) и часто с дополнительным кешированием (varnish)

Собственно, меня в этом вопросе больше всего интересуют пункты 2-3-4 под c#. На nix-системах есть наборы типа imagemagick, gd и специализированные утилиты типа jpegtran -- а под .net я так понимаю всё сводится к работе System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Хочется послушать, что в этом плане есть из рекомедуемых технологий на c#. Код можно не приводить, просто понять общее направление, плюс ссылки приветствуются.

Comment: А почему код не приводить, может кому-то это пригодится? (Мне например). Ответы-ссылки может вами и приветствуются, но SO не приветствуются.

Comment: я бы добавил - 0. использование внешнего хостина картинок :) у imgur вполне приемлимые цены.

Comment: @PashaPash Это есть, под пунктом пять идёт.

Comment: Потому что я конечно эгоист и пойму там, где широкими мазками нарисуют картину и догуглю недостающее -- но отвечающего мне жаль, потому что писать возможно придётся много. Вопрос-то достаточно общий и тянет на хорошую статью.

Comment: Работа с изображениями в .net - это та еще боль. Ничего, кроме побайтового чтения картинок (сюда я отношу и BitMap) для их изменения, я не видел

Comment: Может, что-то из этого будет полезно: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881273/6468198)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Включение Gzip компресии
- Изменение формата на более оптимизированый, например webp [вопрос под webp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566426/webp-library-for-c-sharp).
  Лично я режу качество под 90%, а для изображений без текста под 75-80%
- Плюс под IIS есть такой ресайзер [imageresizing.net](https://imageresizing.net), имеется поддержка webp